# Copying a folder into multiple folders

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with some content which I want to copy into 260 folders, which all are in the same folder.
I guess this is doable with a batch file and a for-loop, but I can't seem to understand how to do it.

Comment: A possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/136725/copy-file-to-multiple-folders-via-batch-script

Comment: Not quite the same issue. The problem I am having is that I want a subfolder (with content) to be copied over to 260 folders. Alternativly I want to transfer a file to a specific subfolder to these 260 folders.

Comment: What are the 260 destination folders? Are they all subfolders in the same location, or are all paths written as separate lines in a text file?

Comment: They are all in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`XCopy`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) for copy the file

```
 xcopy "src\*.*"  "..\..\..\dst" /s /i /c /y
```

and can add the loop `FOR` loop

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,260) do (
   call :Method1
)


:Method1
xcopy "src\*.*"  "..\..\..\dst" /s /i /c /y
GOTO :EOF
```

**Update**

```
FOR /D %%a in ("dst\*") do 
   xcopy "src\*.*"  "%%a" /s /i /c /y
```

Comment: What parts do I change? I guess I have to change (1,1,260) to the main folder where the 260 folders are to be found? And in the XCOPY-part, the "..\..\..\dst"-part, what exactly should I put in here?

Comment: add your source folder with path in `src`  and destination path in `dst`.

Comment: This copies the files in src to the main-folder dst. And not to the subfolders.