# Copying one file to multiple subdirectories with a pattern

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, xcopy

I have the following directory structure

```
>ABC
  >V1
    >XYZ.txt
  >V2
    >XYZ.txt
  >V3
    >XYZ.txt
>DEF
  >V1
    >(Empty)
  >V2
    >XYZ.txt
  >V3
    >XYZ.txt
>PQR
  >V1
    >XYZ.txt
  >V2
    >(Empty)
  >V3
    >XYZ.txt
```

where ABC, DEF,PQR,V1,V2 etc are all directories.

I want to copy a file 123.txt to all the locations **that have XYZ.txt ignoring the empty directories**, so the resultant folder structure looks like this -

```
 >ABC
  >V1
    >XYZ.txt
    >123.txt
  >V2
    >XYZ.txt
    >123.txt
  >V3
    >XYZ.txt
    >123.txt
 >DEF
  >V1
    >(Empty)
  >V2
    >XYZ.txt
    >123.txt
  >V3
    >XYZ.txt
    >123.txt
 >PQR
  >V1
    >XYZ.txt
    >123.txt
  >V2
    >(Empty)
  >V3
    >XYZ.txt
    >123.txt
```

And I need to do this from the command line, preferably using xcopy. I can easily use

```
xcopy "src\*.*"  "..\..\..\dst" /s /i /c /y
```

as explained in this answer ([Copying a folder into multiple folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339403/copying-a-folder-into-multiple-folders)) but I want the copying to happen only where XYZ.txt exists and ignore the other sub-directories.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0559cadd-88c3-457e-8c09-438dc9e06b5a/copy-file-to-multiple-folders?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying a folder into multiple folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339403/copying-a-folder-into-multiple-folders)

Comment: Definitely you need a batch file for this which contains the `IF` statement to check existing XYZ.txt file and then with the errorlevel you can `COPY` the 123.txt.

You can have the `IF` and `COPY` commands in a loop till the directory structure finishes.

Please confirm if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

XCOPY

/U           Copies only files that already exist in destination.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30456620)